# Reading From a .txt File - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read Text file Programmatically using Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492335/read-text-file-programmatically-using-objective-c)

I am using the following lines of Code ::

```
- (void)sync:(NSString *)savedName{

NSLog(@"saved name is this :: %@", savedName);

NSString *savedDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *saveFilePath = [savedDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:savedName];
saveFilePath = [saveFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"edit.txt"];

NSString *saveString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:saveFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 

NSLog(@"saveString is :: %@ savedName : %@ savefilepath : %@", saveString, savedName, saveFilePath);
}
```

The contents of `edit.txt` is :

```
= WWWW =
[[Category:ssss]]
```

What I am trying to do is to read from the file `edit.txt` and store its contents in a string. However, on NSLogging, I get `null` for `saveString`.

I got the following output at `gdb` ::

```
splitView[838:f803] saveString is :: (null) savedName : xxxx savefilepath : /Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D4B3A4CF-E7D0-4D25-B3D3A170A329/Documents/xxxx/edit.t‌​xt`
```

Can someone help me to sort out the error ?? I am unable to figure it out. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Why is your `savedName` parameter null?  You should check that first.

Comment: it is not null .. it is `xxxx`

Comment: oh shoot i mixed up savedName and saveString nevermind

Comment: m sorry .. but I dont think that it is a duplicate !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then what I used to read data from .txt file is as below

```
NSString *path;
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: YOUR_TEXT_FILE_NAME ofType: @"txt"];
```

Now a function to read the file which returns `NSString` as return object.
My call to this function is as below

```
NSString *data = [self readFile: path]];
```

Now the function

```
-(NSString *)readFile:(NSString *)fileName

{
    NSLog(@"readFile");

    NSString *appFile = fileName;    
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appFile])        
    {
        NSError *error= NULL;
        NSString *resultData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: appFile encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error]; 
        if (error == NULL)            
            return resultData;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Happy Coding :)

Comment: how should I define my path here ?? In my code .. I think I have defined my path correctly.

Comment: just use this to read out from the file not to save any file

Comment: i.e. just for `NSString *saveString = [self readFile: path]];` where `path` is same as given above in my answer just put proper name instead of `YOUR_TEXT_FILE_NAME`

Comment: please tell me how to define the path .. I am getting all the more confused.

Comment: ok `path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:edit ofType: @"txt"];` if your file name is `edit.txt` just put `savedName` instead of `edit` because you use `savedName` to save files. Right?

Comment: thanks for the help .. I figured it out .. so long .. Ihad been specifying the wrong path. shitt .. I am really sorry for consuming your time :( It was my bad all the way

Comment: It's my pleaser to help you and also my help is useful to you. YWC

Answer (score 1):

I think that your path to the TXT file is wrong. Check this out the way you are building the  `saveFilePath`, maybe:

```
NSString *savedDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *saveFilePath = [savedDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:savedName];
saveFilePath = [saveFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"edit.txt"];
```

Comment: oh sorry .. my bad .. but still the `saveString` comes out to be null !! I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If ou try :

```
NSString *savedDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *saveFilePath = [savedDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:savedName];
//Why do you do that ? saveFilePath = [savedDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"edit.txt"];

NSString *saveString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:saveFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 

NSLog(@"saveString is :: %@ savedName : %@ savefilepath : %@", saveString, savedName, saveFilePath);
```

Comment: I have more than 1 .txt files in the folder of `savedName`. So, I tried using the specific name for my .txt file.

Comment: I tried your code too .. still it comes out to be null. However, can you explain me as to what the first line of yours does ??

Comment: When I read your code I suspect you to look in the Document directory of your application. Perhaps I'm wrong but if not my code is more common to look on this directory. Please print all the path (with your file name inside) and show us.

Comment: I got the following output :: `splitView[838:f803] saveString is :: (null) savedName : xxxx savefilepath : /Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D4B3A4CF-E7D0-4D25-B3D3A170A329/Documents/xxxx/edit.txt`

Comment: Now fill the error parameter with an NSError variable

Comment: did not get you .. how can I do that ??

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your document contain edit.txt file.

Edit:

```
- (void)sync:(NSString *)savedName{

    NSString *filePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"license.txt"];
    NSString *saveString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 

    NSLog(@"saveString is :: %@ savedName : %@ savefilepath : %@", saveString, savedName, filePath);
}
```

Path of license.txt is: /Users/nuzhat.zari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9BFCE2B5-C976-4EF6-91DF-DA4ABCD04788/Documents.

Make sure your file path is also similar to this.

Comment: yes .. it contains the`.txt. file

Comment: Can you give the path of your edit.txt?

Comment: I have posted the `path` called as `savefilePath` in my return for `NSLog` in my edited question.