# How do I keep text type data on my app using some form of data persistence

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, data-persistence

I need to feed some substantial text into my first app which will change as the date changes (i.e every day) for a whole month.

This data, I currently have it all on a .doc file which each day's content on that file, properly separated.

What method can I use to store this data in my app and how can I format it in such a way that the app takes the date portion of the text and use that to determine whether or not it should show that particular portion of text for a day.

The app will update the content every month.

I've looked everywhere and the posts I've seen about persistent data just confuse me more. Would this be possible using just plists? The data will ALWAYS be text never images or anything else.

Comment: How much text is there per day?  If there is not too much you could store it in a plist.  Otherwise you might want to use separate txt files.  Either way, a word document is not going to help you.

Comment: The text is about 400 words long per day. I'll look into using separate txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post a sample of the text, we can probably give you a better answer (not clear what you're asking), but **this sounds like a perfect candidate for [core data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) or [sqlite](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)**. Once you **have the text separated by date/text combos**, it becomes pretty simple to do a search by the appropriate date, and show only the relevant text.

By the way, having it in a *.doc format is just going to add unnecessary overhead. If you really want to have it in a flat file, use something like json.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HwQ9XZEf
This is just some placeholder text but essentially all days will follow this format.

Comment: yeah, toss that all in a sqlite database or core data. Then just make a field for date, category (what I'm assuming 'LEARNING' is), and the text

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bit much for plists.  You could use core data or sqlite, but there is also the easier option of having separate plaintext files and reading them as is demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492335/read-text-file-programmatically-using-objective-c).