# Reading data from a file in Objective-C, how to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I'm trying to develop an iOS app , that allow the user to enter a word then press the button to get the definition of the word

Actually I have a file which contains the words and their definitions such that

```
Apple , the definition 
orange , the definition
```

I wrote the code but I don't know why it's not working

```
#import "ViewController.h"

NSString *readLineAsNSString(FILE *file);

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize text;
@synthesize lab;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)butt:(id)sender {
    FILE *file = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    NSString *a = text.text ;
    bool found =FALSE;

    while(!feof(file)|| !found )
    {
      NSString *line = readLineAsNSString(file);
        if ((a= [[line componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1])) {
            lab.text = [[line componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];
        }

    fclose(file);
    }
}

@end
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Where are you storing `1.txt`?

Comment: This has been answered already, but you do not need to use `FILE *file` in Objective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492335/read-text-file-programmatically-using-objective-c

Comment: In the folder of the project which contain the header file , main file etc

Comment: Please see the link I posted. If that does not fully answer your question, please update with specifically what does not work.

Comment: That little method contains 2 errors: `a = ` is an assignment, try something like `[a isEqualToString ...` and then you forgot to set `found` to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, a simple way to achieve this is through plist.

Here, a small example to achieve what you want.

**1) Create your plist file.**

In your project, go and "Add New File". In the left column, under iOS (for example), select "Resource". In the main panel select a "Property List" file. Save with a name like "Defs".

Your plist should look like the following.

[image]

**2) Read the plist file** (comments in the code)

```
- (void)readDefinitionsFile
{
    // grab the path where the plist is located, this plist ships with the main app bundle
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defs" ofType:@"plist"];

    // create a dictionary starting from the plist you retrieved
    NSDictionary* definitions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    // JUST FOR TEST PURPOSES, read the keys and the values associated with that dictionary
    for (NSString* key in [definitions allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"definition for key \"%@\" is \"%@\"", key, [definitions objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

**Some notes**

Above a simple example on how to use plist. It does not provide a complete example to achieve what you want. Based on that you will be able to reach your goal.

You should need a property to reference the dictionary you retrieved. So, for example, in your .m.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary* definitions;

@end

@implementation ViewController

// other code here

// within readDefinitionsFile method
self.definitions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Use `definitions` to retrieve the definition you are interested in.

```
NSString* definition = [self.definitions objectForKey:@"aKeyYouWillRetrieveFromSomewhere"];
if(definition) {
    NSLog(@"definition is %@ for key %@", definition, @"aKeyYouWillRetrieveFromSomewhere");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no definition for key %@", @"aKeyYouWillRetrieveFromSomewhere");
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @FoFa See also https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD